# 'Require()' module inside a function doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, require

#### Issue

I'm currently trying to conditionally import an optional JavaScript module.
Meaning, I want to perform some behavior when module X is available, otherwise fallback to Y.

To reach such behavior, I put the `require()` into a `try-catch block`, to catch the error thrown by `require()` when a module couldn't be retrieved.

To reuse this logic and not have to put a `try-catch block` at the top of my files, I outsourced this logic into a function called `optionalRequire()`.
But as soon as I put the `require()` into a function, it can't retrieve any package/module anymore. (See code sinppet and image below)

In the below code snippet I placed a normal `require()`, a `require ()` inside a `try-catch block` and my `optionalRequire()` method next to each other. And as you can see in the below `console image`, everything works as expected, except the `optinalRequire()`.

```
console.log('Debug: Optional Import Test');

// Require Package in the file
const requiredPackage = require('@agile-ts/proxytree');
console.log('Debug: Required Package', requiredPackage);

// Require Packae in a try catch
let tryCatchPackage = null;
try {
  tryCatchPackage = require('@agile-ts/proxytree');
} catch (e) {
  console.log('Debug: Failed');
}

console.log('Debug: TryCatch Package', tryCatchPackage);

// Require Package in a function
function optionalRequire(moduleName) {
  let requiredPackage = null;
  try {
    requiredPackage = require(moduleName);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Debug', e);
  }
  return requiredPackage;
}

const functionPackage = optionalRequire('@agile-ts/proxytree');
console.log('Debug: Function Package', functionPackage);
```

[image]

#### Question

Does anybody know why it can't `require()` any module inside a function?

#### Environment

```
"react": "^16.13.1"
```

https://github.com/agile-ts/agile/tree/master/examples/react/develop/functional-component-ts

#### Example

The weird thing is that it works fine in the `codesandbox` example.
Probably I have misconfigured anything in my current test project.
However, it would be nice to conditionally `require()` something, without configuring anything, since that would be an extra step for the people using the package I'm creating.

https://codesandbox.io/s/import-issue-o10cy?file=/src/core.js